# iPad design dimensions

Tags: website-design, ipad

I am designing for iPad (canvas dimensions 768 x 1004) using the attached mock-up resource. However, I was wondering whether I need to factor the lower navigation bar into my design? I was planning on having a menu bar at the bottom and wondered whether this can sit over that navigation bar or whether I need to work above it. If this is a permanent fixture and I need to work around it then I will crop it off the canvas. Many thanks in advance for your answers. [image]

Comment: it really depends on how you're building the app.

Comment: Before you start, you should find a mockup of the latest iOS. This one is way too old. Also, if you want to export parts of your design as assets, you should work at least in double resolution (@2x) for retina screens. Or better use a vector based design app like http://sketchapp.com or Illustrator. Upscaling a pixel artwork is not something you want to waste your time with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this website- it has all the useful iOs sizings, their resolutions, etc http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-design-cheat-sheet-volume-2/

Answer (score 0):

> @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px)
>
> and (max-device-width : 1024px) { }

Keep holding those formats for optimalisized websites.

Read more information [Here](http://www.studiopress.com/design/website-respond-mobile-devices.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you should also factor in that people might hold heir iPad horizontally when viewing your website.

As for **navigation bars**: take a look at safari, and other browsers, to see what navigation elements are fixed. But since websites are scrollable, this should not concern you. Unless you are you making a website that always fits to the canvas or has events referring to the guy elements (like incision mockups).

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [Tab Bar.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW52) Yes, it is displayed on the screen so it reduces the amount of usable screen space. Yes a developer can add/remove it as they please.

The latest iOS has a translucent Tab Bar so your backgrounds should fill the screen.